# Making object stay on screen OpenGL SFML

Tags: opengl, sfml

I'm drawing a Triangle in OpenGL and you can move it up,down,left right. I'm using SFML as my windowing framework, I want to know how i can keep my triangle in the window and not have it move outside of it i.e. if it goes all the way to the top i want it stop going past the height

Answer (score 0):

That largely depends on you projection matrix. You need to obtain High/Low bounds of it (if you use perspective they will depend on Z-distance; with orthogonal matrix it's easier as Z is squashed) and then check against them - if your object is off - forbid the movement.

Comment: yea i'm using gluPerspective, how do i obtain the high/low bounds then?

Comment: Here's the gluPerspective code: http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GluPerspective_code Z value is uniformly distributed between near and far clipping planes. I don't know if SFML has any shortcuts to achieve your goal, so I would go for custom math solution..